# How do I debug a crash on iOS device from a crash log

Tags: ios

I am getting a new crash which appears to be memory related but can't debug it because it disconnects from the iPhone itself.

Can anyone offer any advice on where to begin - below is the crash log from the device.

BTW: I don't get any crash when running in Simulator.

```
Incident Identifier: 8865CBC4-260B-43D3-B42C-A0F0E5B1676F
CrashReporter Key:   16307a18ed6b8747e97d757b9ba4c1ffd5b091dc
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             Info2iOS [16061]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Info2iOS
Identifier:          au.com.ossh.Info2iOS
Version:             12 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-24 15:40:28.827 +1000
Launch Time:         2015-05-24 15:40:21.970 +1000
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Info2iOS                        0x0000000100133e88 0x100040000 + 999048
1   Info2iOS                        0x0000000100133f04 0x100040000 + 999172
2   UIKit                           0x000000018a48e22c -[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyFromLevel:withBlock:] + 252
3   UIKit                           0x000000018a48e240 -[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyFromLevel:withBlock:] + 272
4   UIKit                           0x000000018a48e52c +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedReleaseArray:block:] + 524
5   UIKit                           0x000000018a48e788 +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedRelease:] + 168
6   UIKit                           0x000000018a403930 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 244
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007dcf90 0x1007dc000 + 3984
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007f4844 0x1007dc000 + 100420
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007df1bc 0x1007dc000 + 12732
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007e16f0 0x1007dc000 + 22256
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856e77f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856e589c __CFRunLoopRun + 1488
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856112d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
14  GraphicsServices                0x000000018ee276f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
15  UIKit                           0x000000018a1d6fa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484
16  Info2iOS                        0x00000001000f68fc 0x100040000 + 747772
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001975daa04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001976d8c24 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007ee584 0x1007dc000 + 75140
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007df098 0x1007dc000 + 12440

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001976f3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.br.notifs-receiver.ipc
Thread 3:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100412168 0x10035c000 + 745832
1   CloudDocs                       0x000000018c28d4c0 -[BRNotificationReceiver watchUbiquitousScopes:bundleID:predicate:] + 280
2   CloudDocs                       0x000000018c2a80fc -[BRQuery _startReceiver] + 76
3   CloudDocs                       0x000000018c2aa610 -[BRQuery notificationsReceiverDidInvalidate:] + 448
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007dcfd0 0x1007dc000 + 4048
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007dcf90 0x1007dc000 + 3984
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007e7db4 0x1007dc000 + 48564
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007e02c0 0x1007dc000 + 17088
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007e8380 0x1007dc000 + 50048
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007e02c0 0x1007dc000 + 17088
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007ea5d0 0x1007dc000 + 58832
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007ec244 0x1007dc000 + 66116
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778d228 _pthread_wqthread + 812
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001976f3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001976f3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.entry.pq
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001977852bc _platform_memmove + 108
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185612088 CFDataReplaceBytes + 492
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856c6c44 __CFDataInit + 884
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856b703c __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 2196
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856b8420 __CFBinaryPlistCreateObject + 24
5   Foundation                      0x00000001865a855c _decodeObjectBinary + 620
6   Foundation                      0x00000001865affcc -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1732
7   Foundation                      0x00000001865855b8 -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) initWithCoder:] + 240
8   Foundation                      0x00000001865a8d94 _decodeObjectBinary + 2724
9   Foundation                      0x00000001865a81b0 _decodeObject + 300
10  Foundation                      0x00000001865a73d8 +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:] + 100
11  CoreData                        0x000000018554437c -[PFUbiquityBaseline loadFileFromLocation:error:] + 1480
12  CoreData                        0x0000000185589128 -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant checkKnowledgeVectorsAndBaselineWithStore:error:] + 2176
13  CoreData                        0x000000018557a8cc -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupForStore:error:] + 2748
14  CoreData                        0x0000000185579b7c -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupWithRetry:] + 160
15  CoreData                        0x000000018553f388 __57-[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntry executeBlockOnPrivateQueue:]_block_invoke + 68
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007dcfd0 0x1007dc000 + 4048
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007dcf90 0x1007dc000 + 3984
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007e7db4 0x1007dc000 + 48564
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007e02c0 0x1007dc000 + 17088
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007ea5d0 0x1007dc000 + 58832
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001007ec244 0x1007dc000 + 66116
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778d228 _pthread_wqthread + 812
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001976f3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019778ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000100496abc   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fdbdd2c
    x4: 0x000000016fdbdd28   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000137e15ea0   x7: 0x0000000000000220
    x8: 0x0000200000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000101a597eb76e1  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000004  x13: 0x0000000043000002  x14: 0x0000000043000004  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x00000001004a2954  x17: 0x0000000196f764dc  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001985d1280
   x20: 0x0000000137e0a2e0  x21: 0x0000000137e0a6a0  x22: 0x000000017405d1f0  x23: 0x0000000000000002
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x0000000000000002  x26: 0x000000018a979a3a  x27: 0x0000000000000048
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fdbe360   lr: 0x0000000100133e88
    sp: 0x000000016fdbe2d0   pc: 0x0000000100133e88 cpsr: 0x80000000

Binary Images:
0x100040000 - 0x100167fff Info2iOS arm64  <5046180ce7f034d798c16bc5b87b709d> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Info2iOS
0x10033c000 - 0x100343fff libBacktraceRecording.dylib arm64  <609085d07ad13f4691673e8ea8eb5ce2> /Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib
0x10034c000 - 0x100353fff libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib arm64  <d2a1b0ab62a63bdb90bdb489460804d3> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
0x10035c000 - 0x1004b7fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <4e512b23f4503d518850fbcf49b457fd> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x100664000 - 0x10066ffff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <e8ce242acdea31798d8ab96497635dc0> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x100694000 - 0x10069bfff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <823d65fe5c7a34129f5603dd23c20e8e> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x1006c0000 - 0x1006c7fff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <cc95466ef53a3514bdf40b139289e108> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x1006f0000 - 0x1006f3fff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <55a76450159b37f3abf9359c448e0d65> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x100708000 - 0x100733fff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <933b5863568532778fbfc694e2f326fe> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x100788000 - 0x10078ffff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <8ac3c4ddc0483f5ea3d6260167f37330> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x1007a4000 - 0x1007a7fff libswiftSecurity.dylib arm64  <d152a0cae27733bda7b876cc388277e5> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftSecurity.dylib
0x1007b4000 - 0x1007bffff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <3894dd8eee17360cb23a1acb264efc23> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/769E926E-03D5-4B13-995B-FAEB4DCECA2F/Info2iOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x1007dc000 - 0x100807fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <efa1635fe58b3188a39f1b22752af330> /usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib
0x120030000 - 0x120057fff dyld arm64  <75c68bbe28b13fcd91014f15139742dc> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183edc000 - 0x184070fff AVFoundation arm64  <c69cb19d6db0339bbfb4c18fa7f4f26c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x184074000 - 0x1840d8fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <fdd31b28c0ec3f76b8f0fa9a057e43d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x18411c000 - 0x18411cfff Accelerate arm64  <a2161063fee1315193bc488d0354f43e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x184134000 - 0x184353fff vImage arm64  <74eb7b77dbcd321db86e784be9353a08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x184354000 - 0x1843fbfff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <56e8b79c2c03379dad45fe2ea1a4052f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x1843fc000 - 0x184776fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <fd491ae19b12315babb621650a0eef76> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x184778000 - 0x18478dfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <9307063a5e1833abbb857a9ec4c5369e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x184790000 - 0x1847f8fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <d4d2b4a941213e2b81f3ddafd6b8a312> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1847fc000 - 0x18481ffff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <92a0dd635be43dfe8c128c888ef37c0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x184820000 - 0x184820fff vecLib arm64  <9248f57f1d8430219a810aa93254f157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x184824000 - 0x184853fff Accounts arm64  <4199851056d4376aa4d8668b83c85454> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x184858000 - 0x1848d6fff AddressBook arm64  <73735c2a294139e5b99ada613fc861ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x1848d8000 - 0x184a2bfff AddressBookUI arm64  <860bc29210ba3d7c80dc83a83388e31c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x184a2c000 - 0x184a40fff AssetsLibrary arm64  <06c85b7fcfaf3722b6e7a89a1ed5559e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x184bf4000 - 0x184eb4fff AudioToolbox arm64  <760c2dc59fa13660a769cc1b052d41e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x185054000 - 0x185267fff CFNetwork arm64  <df5535d1633f375aa889f755db0a93b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x185268000 - 0x185304fff CloudKit arm64  <c24c6a0eeb1a38b598fafc24e9974595> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x185308000 - 0x18536dfff CoreAudio arm64  <b85ca2cdb29639ccb5f6405baf597027> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x185394000 - 0x1853b5fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <fbd7cbc4b2533ea38844bf98757ce58d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x1853b8000 - 0x185604fff CoreData arm64  <af13d4e830e13607b745fe57f90e5d5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x185608000 - 0x185966fff CoreFoundation arm64  <6548b13bef1f3f958d96266f7c4c44e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x185968000 - 0x185acafff CoreGraphics arm64  <92162d42d08d357ab66302a38d724828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x185b20000 - 0x185b22fff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <8f40b7d9b97b344f9c7a5a0b79bdc2b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x185b24000 - 0x185b2ffff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <a40d7bdbbe6c3317bcf4c20c085df848> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x185d24000 - 0x185d42fff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <975284709e51353690ec8a651b43c1db> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x185d44000 - 0x185e76fff CoreImage arm64  <d7a2122dc8173803bc220fde3cfebfdf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x185e78000 - 0x185ed6fff CoreLocation arm64  <a166ad7f12f93406b54ae6a170fb38ee> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x185f10000 - 0x185fd3fff CoreMedia arm64  <403a9798401c3b70a207e0e236454c0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x185fd4000 - 0x1860c2fff CoreMotion arm64  <61338e072f2a385ab4e315975f23eea2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x1860c4000 - 0x186135fff CoreTelephony arm64  <450440ee68593b8e9c951cdf838264f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x186138000 - 0x186240fff CoreText arm64  <4a9633cee0393585a98fcf07410e0828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x186244000 - 0x186261fff CoreVideo arm64  <217e5b69f6d03f8893f01de3e40915a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x186264000 - 0x186388fff EventKit arm64  <f7af75b17dac3c5aa8dc91a1edd1df37> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x18653c000 - 0x186794fff Foundation arm64  <509b484fb7b634b19673d50296d8278f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1867c8000 - 0x1867f1fff GSS arm64  <3dae218853563b1a985b80d6a353bad8> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x1868dc000 - 0x186947fff IOKit arm64  <311bed1f2b893195b8c0564d8925bfa2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x186948000 - 0x186bebfff ImageIO arm64  <7d3c81746f2c3f1488b3efc633d21633> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x186bec000 - 0x18708dfff JavaScriptCore arm64  <1ad0ed311f3e3897bac70f3388fc05be> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1879c8000 - 0x1879cefff MediaAccessibility arm64  <4e3e82a2b09a38fcbf01843f97d5e604> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x1879d0000 - 0x187bf3fff MediaPlayer arm64  <fb0500c5695c36b5b54865f533cc899e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x187bf4000 - 0x188012fff MediaToolbox arm64  <c2103a7dd16e3f67abfe898b039061e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x188014000 - 0x1880e8fff MessageUI arm64  <000bbe6f4a8c32bda9c8ea674a7f200d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x1880ec000 - 0x188164fff Metal arm64  <eb54636e26cd3dee870fa5e4fb708fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x188168000 - 0x188219fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <daa61b358c17365792c20df791224e26> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x189494000 - 0x18949efff OpenGLES arm64  <8824bb82d43937a9b0aa3870ece35772> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x1894a4000 - 0x1894a5fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <34760639fb2331dcaa229ba0e418c1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1894a8000 - 0x1894abfff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <e6f967504d5937d59223598de12969ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1894ac000 - 0x1894b0fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <30969b8fde9f36c4a6a0293c03e74e5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x1894b4000 - 0x1894befff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <5942ea8060c63e86b3ffbfb76b061276> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x1894c0000 - 0x18950bfff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <3e46a6b44be93e5689e4851c76b2db04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x189aa8000 - 0x189c3afff QuartzCore arm64  <e47923f08f343c3e98e77f22f674f234> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x189c3c000 - 0x189c88fff QuickLook arm64  <c7ce94fecae33d839b804000f2ecca60> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x189ec0000 - 0x189f14fff Security arm64  <80b60ba1feba39afb6686e342398cce1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x18a0e8000 - 0x18a15bfff SystemConfiguration arm64  <633d8a8abeaf3abda9b0401146f2b668> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x18a160000 - 0x18aae0fff UIKit arm64  <f67965f71974303e90cfaed997ae36a3> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18aae4000 - 0x18ab5dfff VideoToolbox arm64  <1468c96c3448370bbb407644bedbb368> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18ab98000 - 0x18adfcfff WebKit arm64  <5e03a0bc7ab436ba900562cceb681ef4> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x18b238000 - 0x18b245fff AOSNotification arm64  <bfc45391892b3510ac92ba9362e5100c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x18b3e0000 - 0x18b43efff AccountsDaemon arm64  <e819e315efce3a178391a7dfbee95db0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon
0x18b468000 - 0x18b46dfff AggregateDictionary arm64  <cfa106cd07b430a6959f9127a6c3363a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18b670000 - 0x18b673fff AirPlaySupport arm64  <9379098c9eed33088c7096882eec570d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x18b8c8000 - 0x18b910fff AppSupport arm64  <d088c6263b4932aebd9dcf2a14aadef2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18b914000 - 0x18b96ffff AppleAccount arm64  <0374ffa0f0563b108aa7a58f2c72f39f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x18ba80000 - 0x18baccfff AppleJPEG arm64  <621fe1223e9038a09023dd6c558ce423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18bae0000 - 0x18baf4fff ApplePushService arm64  <38b2aec9a5b5357aa8e1060d28992da3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x18baf8000 - 0x18bb01fff AppleSRP arm64  <8f0cacbeabdf39b3815a72e7ec9e8668> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x18bb14000 - 0x18bb1ffff AssertionServices arm64  <e0f182c7fdcd34a1a4acfe0bd4c7eae3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18bb20000 - 0x18bb3dfff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <e28e74aed7103573b9416e016525ac04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x18bb40000 - 0x18bb80fff AssistantServices arm64  <f8cc50774cbf3007bd3944592b1608e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x18bbbc000 - 0x18bbbffff BTLEAudioController arm64  <ea2ff306f28638ca8bc7a4f02d3c8f1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x18bbc0000 - 0x18bbdcfff BackBoardServices arm64  <ff372ac34d6430829a97778caad5bdf4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18bbe4000 - 0x18bc21fff BaseBoard arm64  <ab16c3464cfb3319bf31202639bb4a90> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18bc3c000 - 0x18bc43fff BluetoothManager arm64  <ab5e74eff0cb32f88338de3fed9495d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x18bc44000 - 0x18bc74fff Bom arm64  <45c2562173063fb2bd0e71bbc3423915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x18bd74000 - 0x18bd7dfff CacheDelete arm64  <c5cb9203a779314ea5616b6cb35c39a0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/CacheDelete
0x18bdd0000 - 0x18be00fff CalendarFoundation arm64  <ce2278a234d0300a8e1c55d93179a8ea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CalendarFoundation.framework/CalendarFoundation
0x18bf4c000 - 0x18bf56fff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <0f8d341d0a8f3828b9485b189d04e126> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x18bf64000 - 0x18c0b0fff Celestial arm64  <0b8842c85d7139848f5e049e8e784c47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x18c0e4000 - 0x18c0eafff CertUI arm64  <5172b3a96c1736b390833483c0832e79> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x18c250000 - 0x18c274fff ChunkingLibrary arm64  <d38656203ca635b883d96b9c82d4cb59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x18c278000 - 0x18c2c2fff CloudDocs arm64  <77c63a3164da35c684ad0a23f032a738> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/CloudDocs
0x18c740000 - 0x18c812fff CloudPhotoLibrary arm64  <f78c8689515a326c8ebe8878d4bb4c52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudPhotoLibrary.framework/CloudPhotoLibrary
0x18c870000 - 0x18c872fff CommonAuth arm64  <f6c3ca737c12362baa27b4d67391b85d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/CommonAuth
0x18c874000 - 0x18c886fff CommonUtilities arm64  <cf917a1cdf503940a9879dda3ea7eae4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x18c888000 - 0x18c88cfff CommunicationsFilter arm64  <f57b126af38139b280188f1e33ae77a2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x18c978000 - 0x18c97dfff ConstantClasses arm64  <b1cc336c6ea1319f8131623918110a89> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x18c980000 - 0x18c9befff ContentIndex arm64  <11771c1154c63b2ea6b3a2759116f76a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x18c9c0000 - 0x18c9c8fff CoreAUC arm64  <ac7f4428bde93a379e4710ff07f8cd82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x18ca04000 - 0x18ca64fff CoreDAV arm64  <0eb42897b04c35558a55ac357b4f4eb5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDAV.framework/CoreDAV
0x18ca68000 - 0x18ca90fff CoreDuet arm64  <2325864ac79931d08384cad9a5c2378c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x18ca9c000 - 0x18caaffff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol arm64  <8e9b82e37ab1398fb75be0114863b188> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x18cab8000 - 0x18cabafff CoreDuetDebugLogging arm64  <9a52d10bde253ae196a436618e6245af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x18cc60000 - 0x18cd98fff CoreMediaStream arm64  <e22f7a3741a33ebd9f7bf3930974f204> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x18cd9c000 - 0x18ce4cfff CorePDF arm64  <48261152791832da9b786ccb6e676ce4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
0x18cec0000 - 0x18cecbfff CoreRecents arm64  <cd48e7d3e01439e1b592864083e40954> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRecents.framework/CoreRecents
0x18cf60000 - 0x18cf84fff CoreServicesInternal arm64  <c35ab32d16e839e5bd3a2d4357cd512b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x18d1ec000 - 0x18d280fff CoreUI arm64  <8e5f6e68de253eb98752939e94219aa8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x18d284000 - 0x18d31efff CoreUtils arm64  <835930892f3f3c28823421061c40dad7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x18d320000 - 0x18d326fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <939d8e00b1a8388eaf6721fe6fed8d07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18d328000 - 0x18d32efff DAAPKit arm64  <996db669e80833e0a44db31c6e094693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAAPKit.framework/DAAPKit
0x18d330000 - 0x18d33bfff DCIMServices arm64  <da6697519919326580a81258865cf9de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DCIMServices.framework/DCIMServices
0x18d33c000 - 0x18d38bfff DataAccess arm64  <7024476be74c3c1d9d7958544753e6d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x18d5e8000 - 0x18d60efff DataAccessExpress arm64  <ba41527f2d0136f787281ddbbe9d2015> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18d660000 - 0x18d667fff DataMigration arm64  <ac8e9c98ebaf3b3facc8a35d4a5f662d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18d684000 - 0x18d685fff DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <446ae998ec433acdac17d08dfb63094d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x18d688000 - 0x18d6a8fff DictionaryServices arm64  <d911eb3e1549338d8a3da77f3cf030ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x18d6d0000 - 0x18d6f6fff EAP8021X arm64  <6201a1545ea735eaa654e6c4f19fce9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x18d830000 - 0x18d832fff FTClientServices arm64  <41e3fe196535314d955d8adf52731b2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x18d834000 - 0x18d866fff FTServices arm64  <063fb60e8c3031189f047aaf77127419> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x18d868000 - 0x18dc95fff FaceCore arm64  <6c9c849bf1173e1892729204b96c95bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x18dd1c000 - 0x18dd1cfff FontServices arm64  <9d2ca68913c53fef976aabcdb3f2bb7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18dd20000 - 0x18de00fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <3e696fd5c611305eaee6bad27362f029> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x18de04000 - 0x18de13fff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <c98491fefd2a34f5a1a5fab3cce3d478> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x18df20000 - 0x18df40fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <06e8a3da46443f858df92288b8b009bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18eae8000 - 0x18eb01fff GenerationalStorage arm64  <c02d99b6f6e138249504e2a9a598e9b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x18eb04000 - 0x18ee19fff GeoServices arm64
```

Comment: @Yossi I don't use that method anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the iPhone to the mac. Go to Xcode -> Window -> Devices. Under devices
select your connected iPhone. Tap on 'View device logs' and then tap on 'All logs'.

The crash should be in this list and if you ran the directly from Xcode to your device, Xcode should be able symbolicate it automatically.

Comment: So do you have the dsym file too? Was the project built on your system or someone else's system? To symbolicate the crash log Xcode needs the dsym file and the .app file created when you built the project.

Comment: Yes I should have all of that.  A bit weird this I just removed the Core Data file from iCloud and rebuilt it from the Mac app and now the crash seems to be gone.  Maybe a corrupt file coming from iCloud.  I had a different crash a week ago which turned out to be one database record with binary data that was crashing the archiver when trying to migrate a Core Database to make a backup.  If it comes back I might need your help @indrajit to track it down further.